# WPF controls do not behave as expected with multi-touch

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

I am creating an application in WPF that relies on multi-touch and, although I can receive multiple touch points, the WPF controls do not behave as expected when multiple touches occur at the same time.

I created a simple test WPF application using buttons for visualization to ensure it wasn't anything in my project causing the issue.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TouchSample3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchSample3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid TouchDown="Grid_TouchDown">
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Height="70" Click="button1_Click" TouchDown="button1_TouchDown"/>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Height="70" Click="button2_Click" TouchDown="button2_TouchDown"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is my MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button 1 clicked.");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button 2 clicked.");
    }

    // TouchDown events
    private void button1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button 1 Touch Down.");
    }

    private void button2_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button 2 Touch Down.");
    }
}
```

When I perform a single touch on either button it fires as expected, the TouchDown event, and Click event along with the button animation occur.

However, when I attempt to do two touches simultaneously (one finger held down, another one pressing), the TouchDown events get fired but the the Click events and the button animations do not happen.

It clearly registers the touch points but I don't understand why it doesn't perform actions/events to the WPF controls when touches happen simultaneously.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats because the old version of Click event is not prepared well for a multi-touch wpf application. It is primary classified as a mouse event, since the TouchDown is touch event primary so it support the multi-touch feature.